# How to store data from a POST method in Node.js/Express and process it in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, post

I have a problem returning the data of an "POST" method into another function so it gets further process. I am using Node.js, JavaScript and Express as the Backend.

Here is the related code in "server.js":

```
app.post("/movies", function (req, res) {
    const imdbIDs = req.body; 
  
    if (!Array.isArray(imdbIDs)) {
      res.sendStatus(400); 
      return;
    }
  
    const apiKEY = '########';   // unvisible just for question
    const movies = [];
    
    
  
    imdbIDs.forEach((imdbID, index) => {
      const apiUrl = `http://www.omdbapi.com/?&apikey=${apiKEY}&i=${imdbID}`;
  
      http.get(apiUrl, (response) => {
        let responseData = '';
  
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
          responseData += chunk;
        });
  
        response.on('end', () => {
          try {
            const movieData = JSON.parse(responseData);
  
            if (movieData.Response === 'True') {
              const movie = {
                Released: new Date(movieData.Released).toISOString(),
                Runtime: movieData.Runtime !== 'N/A' ? parseInt(movieData.Runtime) : null,
                Genres: movieData.Genre.split(',').map(genre => genre.trim()),
                Directors: movieData.Director.split(',').map(director => director.trim()),
                Writers: movieData.Writer.split(',').map(writer => writer.trim()),
                Actors: movieData.Actors.split(',').map(actor => actor.trim()),
                MetaScore: movieData.Metascore !== 'N/A' ? parseInt(movieData.Metascore) : null,
                imdbRating: Number(movieData.imdbRating)
                             
              };
              console.log(movie)   
              movies.push(movie);
            } else {
              console.error(`Error retrieving movie with imdbID ${imdbID}: ${movieData.Error}`);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing movie data:', error);
          }

          if (index === imdbIDs.length - 1) {
            // Send the movies array as the response
            res.status(200).send(movies);           
          }
        });
      }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching movie data:', error);
  
        if (index === imdbIDs.length - 1) {
          // Send the movies array as the response even if there was an error
          res.status(200).send(movies);   
          
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

And here is the function where I want to process the receiving data "index.js":

```
function loadMovies(genre) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    const mainElement = document.querySelector("main");

    while (mainElement.childElementCount > 0) {
      mainElement.firstChild.remove()
    }

    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        .forEach(movie => new MovieBuilder(movie, deleteMovie).appendTo(mainElement))
    } else {

      mainElement.append(`Data could not be loadet, status ${xhr.status} - ${xhr.statusText}`);
    }
  }
  const url = new URL("/movies", location.href)
  if (genre) {
    url.searchParams.set("genre", genre)
  }
  xhr.open("GET", url)
  xhr.send()
}
```

I tried creating a "const movies = (xhr.responseData)" and then calling it, but all I get is an "undefined" value.
To sum up: In "Server.js" I make a "POST" request for a form and all the checked boxes should be stored in a list. That list should be called in "index.js" where the html can be build dynamically.

Comment: `xhr.responseData` would be `undefined` ... did you mean `xhr.responseText` like you actually have in your code?

Comment: yeah, xhr.responseData is undefined, sorry

Comment: Where and how do you call the other function? Do you call the function on the client or server? Can you create and post a [mcve]? Why do you use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch`?

Comment: I think that this is the actual problem. I do not know how to call the other function. And regarding XMLHttpRequest: Its a school project and thus necessary to use XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

- In your server.js, you use app.post('/movies'), the request method is **POST**
- In your index.js, xhr.open("GET"), the request method is **GET**, maybe your server not support **GET** method, you can open browser console and check network, find whether the request of **/movies** is 200 or 404.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).